# Do one action when method is finished in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios9

I want do one action when one method is finished, I execute one method in other method and I want the second method stop until the first method is finished.

I have that method:

```
func ejecutarOBJC(){
    let txtNombre = self.view.viewWithTag(4) as? UITextField
    let textoNombre=txtNombre?.text
    let txtContra = self.view.viewWithTag(5) as? UITextField
    let textoContra=txtContra?.text


    let instanceOfCustomObject: SQLViewController =  SQLViewController()
    instanceOfCustomObject.nombre = textoNombre;
    instanceOfCustomObject.contra = textoContra;
    instanceOfCustomObject.obtenerExistenciaUsuario()

}
```

And also the other method:

```
func otherMethod(){

    ejecutarOBJC()

//I want continue with that method when the execution of the other method finish

}
```

Comment: show some code to make your problem better understandable. Right now I either misunderstood you or the solution is just to call method after method!?

Comment: Put code at the end of the method.

Comment: Call second method from the last line in first method.

Comment: So what is the problem? Is some of the code asynchronous?

Comment: Yes the first method has code asynchronous and I want stop the app until the code finish, also the code asynchronous. @luk2302

Comment: that is not how asynchronous functions work - deal with the fact that it is async. Add a completion block to the async method call and in there continue your work.

Comment: I put completion block and don't run. @luk2302

Answer (score 7):

This is how you would achieve this:

```
func methodOne() {

    //Method one code here

    methodTwo()

}

func methodTwo() {

    //Method Two code here.

}
```

As per your comment, here is how to wait when using async code:

```
func methodOne() {
    //Code goes here
    methodTwo { () -> () in
        //Method two has finished
    }
}

func methodTwo(completion: () -> ()) {
    //Code goes here
    completion()
}
```

Comment: I don't see any async code in your example? If you want to use async code then you will need to use closures to wait until the async code has finished. If you'd like an synch example then please update your question to suit and i'd be happy to amend my answer.

Comment: That code " instanceOfCustomObject.obtenerExistenciaUsuario()" runs a async method in Objective-C.

Comment: Check the second part of my answer, a closure will need to be used. You can return a Block in the Objective C method and by using a closure in swift you will be able to execute code in that block/closure

Answer (score 1):

Use closures:

```
func callCompetionFunction()
{
    // Tira mola meseda (do your stuff)

    completionFunction("a parameter") { () -> Void in
        print("function copleted")
    }
}

func completionFunction(param: AnyObject, completion: ()->Void)
{
    // Do your stuff

    completion()
}
```

To test it in a view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    callCompetionFunction()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func callCompetionFunction()
{
    // Tira mola meseda (do your stuff)
    print("do something here")

    completionFunction("a parameter") { () -> Void in
        print("function copleted")
    }
}

func completionFunction(param: AnyObject, completion: ()->Void)
{
    // Do your stuff
    if param is String
    {
        print("parameter = \(param)")
    }

    print("going to execute completion closure")
    completion()
}


}
```

Comment: I put that in my app and don't run.